# math distribute n objects equidistantly with spacing s

Tags: math, language-agnostic, screen

I have a set of objects i'm moving across the screen. The are going to be either 200 x 200 or 120 x 120 and will only move right or left in the x direction. I need to calculate the starting  positions of the objects

This should be simple math I think, where for objects of size 120x120: 
(zero is the leftmost edge of the screen)

space=10 (pixels)

object0 starts at -120 )

object1 starts at -240 + space

object2 starts at -360 + space

object3 starts at -480 + space

...
object9 starts at -1080 + space

but this isn't working, they get more and more out of alignment the further the calculation goes. When I move them they stay in their out-of-aligned positions, as I'm adding the same amount of motion to each object.

It would also be nice also to compute the starting x positions from any given point instead of manually entering the x positions, accounting for x can be positive or negative.

Comment: Instead of thinking of the object as being 120 pixels wide, if you think of it being 120+space pixels wide, then you can place right "next" to each other to get you're desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getPositionOfNth(int objectWidth, int startPosition, int objectNumber, int space){
    return startPosition + objectNumber * (objectWidth + space);
}
```

Now for your example:

```
getPositionOfNth(120, 0, 0, 10) == 0
getPositionOfNth(120, 0, 1, 10) == 130
getPositionOfNth(120, 0, 2, 10) == 260
getPositionOfNth(120, 0, 2, 10) == 390
...
```

Comment: so startposition=objectnumber*(objectwidth+space) if I read this correctly?

Comment: startposition+objectnumber*(objectwidth+space) //plus not equal

Comment: Hi Petar, what do you mean by "plus not equal"? What language are you using? I understand == to mean not equal,  I tested your example function (without the == stuff, I don't know what that is) using startPosition= -120 and everything came out to the right of 0 instead of to the left, although spaced correctly, so I stuck a minus in front of the function call and it comes out correctly.